# jQuery Validate - remote not firing

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

Here is my JS code:

```
var _register_form = $('form[name="register"]');
  _register_form.validate({
      ignore: '.ignore',
      rules: {
          hidden_recaptcha: {
              required : function() {
                  if(grecaptcha.getResponse() == '') {
                      return true;
                  } else {
                      return false;
                  }
              }
          },
          email: {
              required: true,
              email: true,
              remote: "../../ajax/check-email.php"
          }
      },
      errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
          error.appendTo(element.prev());
      }
  });
```

My file structure is like:

```
assets/
    js/
      main.js
ajax/
    check-email.php
```

When I click submit, nothing happens. No error messages, no form action. Nothing.

Comment: Remote wouldn't be used like a directory set the site url, something like my site.com/email.php

Comment: What does `_register_form.valid()` returns ? Is it false? Is there any error? also check network activities from developer tools.

Comment: @WalksAway Is there no way to use relative paths?

Comment: @Qsprec it returns true

Comment: did you try to add submit handler 'submitHandler: function(form) {_register_form.ajaxSubmit(); }'. Let validate library to take care of your form submit since remote validation is asynchronous in its execution as far as i know.

Comment: @Frog still nothing

Answer (score 0):

The `remote` path is relative to ***the page*** where the JavaScript is included, **not** to where your JavaScript file is located.

```
assets/
    js/
      main.js
ajax/
    check-email.php
page.php
```

If your page is a sibling of `ajax`, then the `remote` path should be `ajax/check-email.php`